# RProvider and Deedle require different FSharp.Core version

Tags: c#, .net, r, deedle, r.net

I want to write a F# Library that is used in a C# Application.
The purpose is F# library get an input Deedle Frame and use an R script to calculate and return an output Deedle Frame. So in my Visual Studio 2013 solution, there are two projects: one F# library (called RRunner) and one C# console application (which uses the RRunner library). Both of projects use Nuget package: Deedle.RPlugin

```
type RRunner() = 
static member CreateFrameList(input: Frame<int,string>) : Frame<int,string> =
    R.assign("input", input) |> ignore
    let script = R.source(rScriptPath)
    let result: Frame<int, string> = script.GetValue()
    result
```

Inside C# code

```
var result = RRunner.RRunner.CreateFrameList(inputFrame);
```

The above F# code works well. However, when I change the return type of **CreateFrameList** method to:

```
static member CreateFrameList(input: Frame<int,string>) : List<Frame<int,string>> =
    R.assign("input", input) |> ignore
    let script = R.source(rScriptPath)
    let result: List<Frame<int, string>> = script.GetValue()
    result
```

I can build the F# project successfully, but I can not build the C# project.
The error message:

```
Assembly 'RRunner, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

What is the problem with my code? And How to solve this problem? or Is there any other way to resolve my purpose to run R script (that receives a Deedle Frame and returns a List of Deedle Frames) in C# code.

Comment: You can add `app.config` to your console application and specify binding redirect: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/01/30/how-to-use-fsharpcore-430-when-all-you-have-is-431/

Comment: Thanks, @Tomas Petricek. I tried this solution before, but it didn't work. I still got the same error message.

Comment: Hi @Tomas Petricek, I changed the Target F# Runtime of F# project to Fsharp 3.0 and it works well now. But does Deedle.RPlugin support .Net Framework 4.0? I got error message: _The namespace or module 'RProvider' is not defined_ with .Net 4.0